# hiding browser navigation status bar for google chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, href

I'm trying to  to disable google chrome browser navigation status bar on the bottom left for a full screen web app that will be used on touch screen panel. I have a working code for jQuery but I can't use that since my code based on pure JavaScript.

Only workaround find is to remove all href tags on mouse hover, keep the data temporarily on a data tag and once it's click navigate to link as how it is suppose to be using the data tag.

here is how it looks like without disabling it once its hover.
[image: browser navigation status on google chrome]

I was able to remove the href with JavaScript but couldn't add the links afterwards.

```js
var linksAhref = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
var linksData = document.getElementsByTagName('[href]'); 
     
var replaceFunc = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < linksAhref.length; i++) { 
        var href = linksAhref || linksData;
        // console.log(href);
        linksAhref[i].removeAttribute("href");
        // window.location.href = href;
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < linksAhref.length; i++) { 
    linksAhref[i].addEventListener('mouseover', replaceFunc);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="link-1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link-2">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link-3">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="link-4">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code that works in jQuery: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tankucukhas/yu3we54k/):

Comment: How do you expect `document.getElementsByTagName('[href]')` to work? That's not a tag name, it's an attribute. You seem to be confusing this with `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Funny... What kind of a «special purposes» is that? Even if someone tell you how to re-add the links (I looked at your fiddle), these will show in the browser navigation status bar. User will have time to check it before his click. AND THAT'S GOOD! So...

Comment: You can remove all href's, then add them as other attribute on same elements (like: data-original-href="href"), then add click event handler on links to open the link stored on the new attribute using (window.location.href)

Comment: Sorry my question was not so detailed, I have edited a bit. The special purpose is I have a touch screen app that I don't want google chrome to display the link once the links are clicked because it seems odd for user experience-wise on full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an additional attribute such as `data-href` or `data-navigateUrl` with the original link information and restore it when the mouse leaves the link using the event `mouseleave`. Example follows in second fiddle.

If you actually use `jQuery` the code will get much simpler.

**Be aware** that the user can see the target url anyway, by viewing the source code of your page.

**Your solution would have a better performance in this case you want any HTML to be clickable and navigate to the desired destination. You wouldn't have to add and remove `a`'s href everytime. The solution would be way simpler:**

```js
 $('[data-navigateUrl]').click(navigate);

function navigate() {
  window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-navigateUrl');
}

function navigatehRef(element) {
  window.location.href = element.getAttribute('data-href');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span onclick="navigatehRef(this)" data-href="link.htm"> Link 1 (with inline function call), attribute is <b> data-href</b></span> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <span onclick="window.location.href='link2.htm'"> Link 2 (inline redirect), <b>no data-...</b> attribute </span> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-navigateUrl="link3.htm"> Link 3 with function call updated by jQuery at startup, attribute is <b> data-navigateUrl</b></span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now based strictly on your question (using `a` elemets witht the same base-code), the solution would be:

```js
var linksAhref = document.getElementsByTagName('a');


var replaceFunc = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < linksAhref.length; i++) {

    linksAhref[i].removeAttribute("href");
  }
};
var restoreLinkFunc = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < linksAhref.length; i++) {
    linksAhref[i].setAttribute("href", linksAhref[i].getAttribute("data-href"));

  }
};


var clickFunc = function() {
  window.location.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
};

for (var i = 0; i < linksAhref.length; i++) {
  linksAhref[i].addEventListener('mouseover', replaceFunc);

  linksAhref[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', restoreLinkFunc);
  linksAhref[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="link-1" data-href="link-1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="link-2" data-href="link-2">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="link-3" data-href="link-3">Link 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="link-4" data-href="link-4">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like that! It's some kind of a joke! «Try to click me you! I' a shy link.» lmao.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's the `catch me if you can` kinda link :) :P

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the reply, if you check the jQuery example it still clicks through the link however It seems on your code it does not navigate to the link.

Comment: @TanKucukhas on my browser it does not navigate. If you are looking to navigate there is actually much simpler solutions, for example : `<span onclick="window.location.href=this.getAttribute('data-navigateUrl')" data-navigateUrl="link.htm" > Link </span> ` . I updated the answer with that possibility.

Comment: @TanKucukhas I can see that you added another link to the jsFiddler. The new answer I provided might be of good use for you.

Comment: Actually fiddle was always there, I have just added more detail to my question to make it more clear.  I have found a solution would better work for my case since I cannot edit the url's itself because some of them are generated dynamically.  Thanks for the effort though helped me find a work around.

Comment: @TanKucukhas IMHO the first option (I added in my answer) seems to be more effortless (in terms of coding, and browser processing) than the one you provided on your answer. You would just need to set styles on your CSS to format it to any browser/device to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I have find a solution that would work for my case.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

//remove actual href's and set their data to data-href instead
var replaceFunc = function() {
 var href = this.getAttribute("href");
  this.removeAttribute("href");
 this.setAttribute('data-href', href);
};

//navigate to data-href
var navigateFunc = function() {
  window.location = this.getAttribute('data-href');
};

//href will be removed once link is hovered
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].addEventListener('mouseover', replaceFunc);
}

//on click it will navigate url stored in data-href
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].addEventListener('click', navigateFunc);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="link-1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link-2">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link-3">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link-4">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```